# How can I use firebase increment function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am looking for a way when any document added in collection of firestore it increment key in document.

My Code :

```
firestore().collection('booking').add({
    bookingTime: bookingDate,
    userId: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid,
    timeslotId: selectedTimeSlot.timeslotId,
    bookingId: getBookingId(),
    appoitmentTime : selectedTimeSlot.displatString,
    age : info.age,
    gender : info.gender,
    name : info.name,
    phonenumber : info.phonenumber,


  })
    .then(docRef => {
      console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
      firestore().collection('booking').doc(docRef.id).update({numberOfAppoitment: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)});

    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
    })
```

Currenty in `numberOfAppoitment`, it add only 1. I want something increment as new data added

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do here.  Why aren't you just setting numberOfAppoitment at the same time you add the document, along with all the other fields?  Why does it need to be set later?

Comment: Yes i can do that. but my problem is that i want that field auto increment either adding at same time or after addding

Comment: perhaps this documentation -> https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/FieldValue.html#.increment
or this tutorial -> https://fireship.io/snippets/firestore-increment-tips/
Can help you to get the desire behaviour. Do you still need help with this issue?.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can increment a field that doesn't have an integer value at the time of the update.  You should populate the field with in an initial value of 0 if you want to use `FieldValue.increment()` later.

```
firestore().collection('booking').add({
    numberOfAppoitment: 0,
    // include the other fields here...
})
```

You might also want to consider the spelling of the field correctly as "nubmerOfAppointment".

Comment: HI thanks for the responce. but its not possible that if there is 3 document added in collection. then i add new document with increment field it add 4 value in that document